# How to dynamically pass function names and inputs to multiprocessing.process?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Am trying create a utility using `multiprocessing.process` which should be imported to other modules  so when using `process`, I can able to give different input for process, but am not sure how to pass different function names dynamically. To the background of this, while using `pool`, some of my objects are not picklable, so proceeding with process.

```
def mp_handler(self, method_name, input):
    try:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=method_name.func_name, args=(input,))
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error("ERROR2 : " + str(traceback.format_exc()))
        raise Exception

def _read(self, filename):
    logger.info("reading the file" + filename)
    time.sleep(10)

def call(self):
    for func, i in rage(10), [self._read]:
        try:
           self._mp_handler(func, i)
        exception:
           logger.error("ERROR2 : " + str(traceback.format_exc()))
           raise Exception
```

Comment: We need a [MCVE] to help here to have the slightest idea what you're actually trying to pass around. Among other things, `for func, indx in input['val'], [self.read]:` is incredibly suspicious (it's possible it's correct, but highly unlikely).

Comment: dont mention improper sentences like, **blah blah**